# Snowflake - Reconciliation of two tables based on keys

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector, reconciliation

I have two tables (primary and secondary) and we need to do a row and column-level reconciliation between these two tables and get a summary of the differences between these tables.

Table A:

| col_A | col_B | col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| Four | Five | Six |
| Seven | Eight | Nine |

Table B:

| col_A | col_B | col_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| Four | Five | ABC |
| Seven | Eight | Nine |
| Nine | Eight | Nine |

In the above table col_A is the primary key column. I want to compare Table A and Table B and produce results like below.

Matched Rows: 2

Unmatched Rows: 1

Columns not matching: col_C (sample key: Four)

Rows Present in Table A but not in B: 0

Rows Present in Table B but not in A: 1 ( Sample key:Nine)

Generally, Table A and Table B have approx. billion rows. What would be the efficient way to do it in Snowflake.

Comment: Please include sample data and desired results as it's not clear what reconciliation means here and what a "difference" would be.

Comment: added more details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

For row comparison, consider the [`MINUS`/`EXCEPT`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#minus-except) set operator.

```
SELECT count(*) as countOfRowsInTable1NotInTable2 FROM 
( 
    SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C FROM table1
    MINUS 
    SELECT col_A, col_B, col_C FROM table2
)sub;
```

You can reverse the order of the inner SELECT statments to get the same count for tableB. You can also perform a `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` if you want to see which rows exist in one table but not the other.